# Why am I getting duplicate key errors while using a ConsistentHashingPool?

Tags: akka.net

According to the [docs](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html#consistenthashing), one can specify the key they want to utilize for the consistent hash pool by passing a simple lambda to the pool like this

```
var props = Context.DI().Props<ProcessUserSessionActor>()
                .WithRouter(new ConsistentHashingPool(10000)
                    .WithHashMapping(b => ((ProcessUserSession)b).UserId.ToString())); //<==== this line
```

However, when the **first** message through my system passes in I get an error like this

> Couldn't route message with consistent hash key [882f862b-a502-4289-b1f1-fca9a9e1f3c8] due to [An item with the same key has already been added. Key: [2135871908, akka://TradeProcessingSystem/user/$a/$a/$a/$Drc]]

To get a better picture, here is all relevant code

```
var props = Context.DI().Props<ProcessUserSessionActor>()
                .WithRouter(new ConsistentHashingPool(10000)
                    .WithHashMapping(b => ((ProcessUserSession)b).UserId.ToString()));

            Receive<ProcessUserSession>(a =>
            {
                var userSessionProcessor = Context.ActorOf(props);
                userSessionProcessor.Tell(a); //<=== breaks on this line
            });
```

I've even tried deriving my command `ProcessUserSession` from `IConsistentHashable` but I still get the same error. I'm guessing there is something going on under the covers that I am unaware of. My DI setup has al actors registered as `Transient` and so it almost seems like some how the actor is being created on `Context.ActorOf` and some how again on `userSessionProcess.Tell` because the router should have no context on how to create the router until the message actually hits the handler.

**Has anyone had any experience creating ConsistentHashable actors using DI and this routing strategy before that could help point out my mistake?**

Comment: Could you better describe what are you trying to achieve here? I have strong suspicion that you're using this feature for something that should be achieved with Akka.Cluster.Sharding: https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/#why-not-just-use-consistent-hash-cluster-routers-to-distribute-state

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to ensure that each user always has only 1 actor processing his data. This way I can avoid any race conditions, db concurrency exceptions etc. I took a look at the article, I've since then edited my router to contain `new ConsistentHashingPool(1)` I have no idea if this will work once I send a different key (I'm still building the system) so I wonder if data will still be spliced in the way the article mentions.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but creating a pool with 10,000 actor instances is a very bad idea. Even 1000 actors can eat up to 2 GB of memory.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but couldn't.
Here's a Github link for an example project: https://github.com/Arkatufus/ConsistentHashingPoolExample